# SQL query get error "Specified cast is not valid."

Tags: c#, api, boolean

I have sample codes as below:-

```
public List<Announcement_User> announcementUser([FromBody]MyAnnouncementUser value)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = WebApiConfig.conn();
    MySqlCommand query = conn.CreateCommand();
    query.CommandText = "select a.title,a.description,a.date_created,ua.read,ua.announcement_id,ua.user_announcement_id from announcement a left join user_announcement ua on a.announcement_id = ua.announcement_id where ua.user_id = @user_id";

    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", value.user_id);

    var prodWishlist = new List<Announcement_User>();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        prodWishlist.Add(new Announcement_User(null, null,null, false, 0, 0, ex.ToString()));
    }

    MySqlDataReader fetch_query = query.ExecuteReader();

    while (fetch_query.Read())
    {
        prodWishlist.Add(new Announcement_User(fetch_query["title"].ToString(), fetch_query["description"].ToString(), fetch_query["date_created"].ToString(), (bool)fetch_query["read"], fetch_query.GetInt32(4), fetch_query.GetInt32(5), null));
    }
    conn.Close();
    return prodWishlist;
}
```

And I hit error as below:-

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>
> "ExceptionMessage": "Specified cast is not valid.",
>
> "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidCastException",

Now I suspect the error caused by bool. May I know how can I write correct way for bool in(fetch_query.Read())? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What is `read` in the database?

Comment: what is the value of `fetch_query["read"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`GetBoolean`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_GetBoolean_1.htm) method:

```
fetch_query.GetBoolean("read")
```

Comment: 1) `GetBoolean` takes only an `int`(the ordinal) 2) This should throw the same error

Comment: exception could be thrown in any of these places: `(bool)fetch_query["read"], fetch_query.GetInt32(4), fetch_query.GetInt32(5),` not only the one you've specified.

Comment: @TimSchmelter 1) is not true, follow the link in the answer. It accepts a string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter 2) if `ua.read` is a boolean db field. This will not throw the error.

Comment: OP pointed to`SqlDataReader.Read()` method which returns boolean value. There's no possibility for that method to throw this kind of exception: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SynerCoder: if it was then OP's code `(bool) fetch_query["read"]` would also not throw an error there. Didn't know that  `MySqlDatareader.GetBoolean` has the overload for the column name

Comment: @m.rogalski He said: `May I know how can I write correct way for bool in(fetch_query.Read())?` I took that to mean the body on the loop headed by the `fetch_query.Read()`. Because of the fact the exception cann't come from that line.

Comment: Hi SynerCoder, i tried your answer and it's work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you to retrieve all of the values beforehand using column name instead of column index and create new object when required parameters have values:

```
string title = fetch_query["title"].ToString();
string description = fetch_query["description"].ToString();
// ...
object read = fetch_query["read"];
object integer1 = fetch_query[4];
// ...

// newest C# approach
if ( read != null && bool.TryParse(read.ToString(), out bool b_read) )

// old c# approach
bool b_read = false;
if ( read != null && bool.TryParse(read.ToString(), out b_read) )
```

Check for every required property

```
prodWishlist.Add(
    new Announcement_User(
        title,
        description, 
// ..
        b_read,
        i_integer1
//...
));
```